# How to combine two lists into a third list?

Tags: python, list

I got  three list of lists:

```
A=[[9, 'a'], [0, 'c'], [2, 'g'], [7, 'w'], [0, 'Q']]
B=[[0, 'a'], [0, 'c'], [0, 'w'], [0, 'Q'], [3, 'front'], [5, 'Z']]
C=[[9, 'a'], [0, 'c'], [7, 'w'], [0, 'Q']]
```

and I want to combine A and B into C like this:

```
C=[[9, 'a'], [0, 'c'],[7, 'w'], [0, 'Q'],[2,'g'], [3,'front'],[5,'Z']]
```

Basically list with g is not in C so I append into C.Same for list B.

EDIT:I do not need a specific index just append into C.The output is just an example output.It can be in any order.

Comment: "that" index? What index?

Comment: Do you mean a list that is a unique set of A and B?

Comment: Please clarify how to determine the ordering of elements in C

Comment: If the alphabet in A or B is not in C append into C the list with the alphabet.The numbers in the list doesn't matter.

Comment: But doing that won't produce the same output list 'C' as shown in the question

Comment: The output is just an example output.It can be in any order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly, it sounds like you want to add to C values from A and B that were not already in it, making a set of unique values?
If so, this is the way to go:

```
C = [list(x) for x in set(tuple(x) for x in A+B+C)]
```

Comment: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

Comment: Just edited to fix that -- I just realized that lists are unhashable.

Answer (score -1):

```
from itertools import zip_longest
for x,y in zip_longest(enumerate(A),enumerate(B)):
    for i in x,y:
        if i is not None and i[1][1] not in map(lambda i: i[1], C):
            if(i[0] < len(C)):
                C.insert(i[0], i[1])
            else:
                C.append(i[1])
print(C)
```

In order to have the location data as you outlined, this approach seems to work. It's output is: 
[[3, 'front'], [5, 'Z'], [7, 'w'], [0, 'Q'], [0, 'c'], [0, 'w'], [9, 'a'], [2, 'g'], [0, 'a']]